# increment jquery for foreach php

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, increment

I have this foreach:

```
<?php foreach($news as $key => $new) : ?>
    <div class="search-img img-id<?php echo($key); ?>" style="display:none;">
        <img alt="<?php echo($new->n_title); ?>" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?php   echo($new->n_image); ?>" />
    </div>

<h4><span class="search-name<?php echo($key); ?>"><?php echo($noutate->n_title); ?></span></h4>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this script:

```
<script>
$().ready(function(){
     $(".search-name<?php echo($key); ?>").hover(function(){$(".img-id<?php echo($key); ?>").fadeIn(100);},
         function(){$(".img-id<?php echo($key); ?>").fadeOut(80);});
     });
</script>
```

And, as I see and I know, jquery doesn't like php :)
How should I proceed to have this classes with incremented numbers? Like search-name0, search-name1, search-name2 .... etc.

Thank you!

Comment: I see nothing wrong (well, as long as freedom goes) with this approach, except that you will have to do this either in a .php script, or set your php.ini in a way that .js files are parsed by php.

Comment: @Bonatoc I think his problem is that his `script` isn't inside the php foreach

Comment: @19greg96 - you may be correct.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me. Is this the same php page? Or a js-script with php in it? And do you have any errors?

Comment: actually the script is inside the foreach...I didn't wrote like this here....but is not working..

Comment: Use Chrome Dev Tools console to properly debug, and see my below answer with the "rel" approach. You should not have your jquery code loop through a php loop, it is "writing for nothing".

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using  Jquery's **$(this)**, and store your ID in the rel tag :

```
<h4><span class="search-name" rel="<?php echo($key); ?>">
```

and use it this way :

```
<script>
$().ready(function(){

$(".search-name").hover(function(){

 var target_id = $(this).attr('rel');

 $(".img-id"+target_id).fadeIn(100);},
 function(){$(".img-id"+ target_id).fadeOut(80);
 });

 });
 </script>
```

This way, you are a bit more decoupled from PHP.